# compare date in a text file | shell

Tags: shell, awk, sed

I have a file which contains a date at column 7, my requirement is to compare it with today's date and if it is less then it, than remove that complete line.
Also if any date mentioned at column 7 is more then 15 days then modify it to maximum 15 days

example below-

```
now="$(date +'%d-%m-%Y')"
now=24-02-2021
```

file.txt

```
abc    xyz        pqr NFS     5       abc.vol
abc    xyz        pqr NFS     50      xyz.bal     23-02-2021
abc    xyz        pqr NFS     5       abcd.xyz
abc    xyz        pqr NFS     15      pqr.vol     25-02-2023
abc    xyz        pqr NFS     5       xyz.bal     24-03-2021
abc    xyz        pqr NFS     3       pqrst.vol   19-01-2019
```

output should be-

```
abc    xyz        pqr NFS     5       abc.vol
abc    xyz        pqr NFS     5       abcd.xyz
abc    xyz        pqr NFS     15      pqr.vol     11-03-2021
abc    xyz        pqr NFS     5       xyz.bal     24-03-2021
```

I tried through awk but it's fully not working

```
awk -v d=$now '$7 == "" && $7 < d' file.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following GNU awk solution:

```
awk 'NF == 6 { print;next } { OFS="\t";split($7,map,"-");depoch=mktime(map[3]" "map[2]" "map[1]" 00 00 00");if (depoch<systime()) { next };if (+depoch>(systime()+1296000)) { $7=strftime("%d-%m-%Y",(systime()+1296000)) } }1' file.txt
```

Explanation:

```
awk 'NF == 6 { print;                                                    # If there is no date, print the line and skip to the next
               next 
             } 
             { OFS="\t";                                                 # Set the output field delimiter to tab
               split($7,map,"-");                                        # Split the date into the array map (getting day, month and year)
               depoch=mktime(map[3]" "map[2]" "map[1]" 00 00 00");       # Create epoch format of the date
               if (depoch<systime()) { 
                  next                                                   # If epoch format of date is less than today, skip to the next record
               };
               if (depoch>(systime()+1296000)) { 
                  $7=strftime("%d-%m-%Y",(systime()+1296000))            # If the date is greater than today +15 days, set the date to the date + 15 days (1296000 seconds) and format accordingly using strftime
               }  
              }1' file.txt
```

I'm assuming that the required output posted is incorrect. 24-03-2021 is greater than 15 days from today and so should be changed to 11-03-2021

Answer (score 0):

You are on right track, try changing your condition part in your code. Why its NOT working is you are asking `awk` program to check if 7th field is NULL and meantime its value is lesser than variable which means performing same condition in other words so if a 7th field is NULL that will be for sure lesser than mentioned date. For getting results which are actually NOT NULL and having lesser date from current date, by your present condition you will only get those fields whose 7th field is NULL basically, so change it to OR condition to get lines if 7th field is empty OR lesser than today's date then print it simply.

```
now="$(date +'%d-%m-%Y')"
awk -v d=$now '$7 == "" || $7 < d' Input_file
```